Configuring a driver to composite based on active camera
I have a list of cameras that are on different pass indexes (via Object>Relations>Pass Index)

I want to change the background in compositing based on the currently active camera, and am trying to use bpy.context.scene.camera.pass_index to define the value of the driver, but I'm met with the following error:

I'm not really sure what these errors mean, or how to fix them. I'm not married to this approach, either, if there's a better way.

Note: when I remove the expression completely, I see "Python restricted for security" which I also don't know how to get rid of. I'd prefer to modify my python execution permissions on this project rather than sign a blank check for any blend file I might download in the future.

Fixed it. It probably had to do with python restriction. You can just create a driver based off the expression bpy.context.scene.camera.pass_index using the following:

This will update as the active camera changes throughout the animation, provided the render passes are configured correctly as defined in the question.
To tutorialize this for fun, right click value node to add or edit driver:

add a variable, this will be based on the scene. We're doing that because the scene.camera is the active camera

Then, the "path" is the pass_index of the camera in the scene.

Typically pass_index is used on objects which are viewed by the camera to be able to separately edit this vs that object in compositing, but here we're hacking the value to composite based on the currently active camera.
I don't know how this might affect a multi-scene render. We'll cross that bridge when we get to it. LMK if you have any ideas.
